# Rails3 deletes me HABTM records when callback returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have got this model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  before_destroy do |u|
    if u.superadmin? and User.joins(:roles).where(:roles => {:superadmin => true}).count == 1
      u.errors.add(:base, "cannot delete last admin user")
      return false
    end
    return true
  end
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

When I try to delete last superadmin, the before_destroy callback adds to errors array and return false. I get the error message in the controller, everything seems to be fine.

**Except** Rails3 **deletes me record from the join table**. **Why**? I returned false, as I return false it should **not proceed** with the deletion. Here is the log:

```
SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."superadmin" = 't'
AREL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "roles_users" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = 1 AND "roles_users"."role_id" IN (1, 4)
Organization Load (0.4ms)  SELECT * FROM "organizations" INNER JOIN "organizations_users" ON "organizations".id = "organizations_users".organization_id WHERE ("organizations_users".user_id = 1 )
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of web "content" suggesting that returning false doesn't behave as people expect. Those same sources suggest that redirecting or rendering in the before filter is the "Rails Way" to solve this problem, though I've no opinion about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like this rails error, if you use older Rails version (it should be solved in Rails 3.0.6 AFAIK):

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6191-habtm-association-is-being-destroyed-before-the-before_destory-callbacks-are-executed

Comment: Plus using "return" statement in a block is a really bad idea. Thanks!